# Error using webdriver-manager with pyinstaller

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver, pyinstaller, webdriver-manager

My webdriver-manager worked perfectly but when I made .exe file with pyinstaller I got error below. I find out that if I won't put --noconsole to pyinstaller command it will work but with --noconsole the program isn't working.
Here is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver.get("https://www.google.com/")
driver.quit()
```

Here is how I created .exe file with pyinstaller:

```
pyinstaller --onefile --noconsole script.py
```

Here is the error which I got:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "script.py", line 797, in program2
  File "webdriver_manager\chrome.py", line 23, in __init__
  File "webdriver_manager\driver.py", line 54, in __init__
  File "webdriver_manager\utils.py", line 139, in chrome_version
  File "os.py", line 983, in popen
  File "subprocess.py", line 804, in __init__
  File "subprocess.py", line 1142, in _get_handles
OSError: [WinError 6] The handle is invalid
```

Thanks for help!

Comment: should be fixed in webdriver-manager 3.5.0 released yesterday

Answer (score 2):

If you use the version of **webdriver_manager > 3.4.2**, then this bug must to be fixed already.

If you use the version of **webdriver_manager <= 3.4.2**, then the error still persists.

[Here](https://github.com/SergeyPirogov/webdriver_manager/pull/198) is the pull request discussion on the project's Github, which fixes the issue.

To fix the error by ourselves, we need to make changes in `webdriver_manager/utils.py` - import additional module and change two functions:

1. Import `subprocess` module in the beginning

   ```
    import subprocess
   ```
2. Please find the snippet in `def chrome_version()`:

   ```
    with os.popen(cmd) as stream: 
        stdout = stream.read()
   ```
3. And change it with the following:

   ```
    with subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.DEVNULL, stdin=subprocess.DEVNULL,
                          shell=True) as stream:
        stdout = stream.communicate()[0].decode()
   ```
4. Repeat step above for `def firefox_version()`.

Highly recommend to do everything above only in case you are sure you can revert changes.

Comment: This only partially worked for me. The original console was hidden, though it ended up opening another console which displayed different logs? I tried this combo and got the console to disappear after 5 seconds with subprocess. Popen(cmd, shell=False, creationflags=0x00000008, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.DEVNULL, stdin=subprocess.DEVNULL) as stream:
    stdout = stream.communicate()[0].decode()
    version = re.search(pattern, stdout)